# DNN 7 Open a page/module in a modale

Tags: dotnetnuke

Working on DNN 7 , I have a grid where I display somes users infos.
I would like to set an "edit action", to edit the user, like into admin panel.

So I choose to make a modale into the same page.

```
<rad:GridTemplateColumn HeaderStyle-Width="0" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" AllowFiltering="False">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <a href="#" data-id="<%#((CustomerViewModel)Container.DataItem).UserID%>" class="e">
            <img src='<%=ResolveUrl("~/Icons/Sigma/Edit_16x16_Standard.png")%>' title='Edit user' />
        </a>
    </ItemTemplate>
</rad:GridTemplateColumn>

// edit user infos
$('.e').click(function () {
    var url = "<%= GetEditUrlUser() %>".replace(new RegExp("KEYFIELD", "g"), $(this).attr("data-id"));
    //alert(url);
    dnnModal.show(url, true, 550, 950, false, '');
    return false;
});
```

And here my cs function

```
public string GetEditUrlUser()
    {
        // I need to show "dnndev.me/en-us/Admin/User-Accounts/ctl/Edit/mid/"+ModuleId+"/UserId/KEYFIELD/filter/All/pagesize/10/currentpage/0?popUp=true ";
        var url = Globals.NavigateURL("393", "Edit", "mid=" + ModuleId, "UserID=KEYFIELD", "filter/All/pagesize/10/currentpage/0", "popUp=true");
        return url;
    }
```

But that's not good, since Globals.NavigateURL() return me the page where I am.

I have also took a look about `ResolveUrl()` function, but didn't succeed to do something well.

So if someone can help me, or give me an example / tips, it would be great.

Thanx

EDIT : It working with this code, but it doesn't seems optimised and really great

```
public string GetEditUrlUser()
    {
        var url = Globals.NavigateURL("Edit", "mid","393","UserID","KEYFIELD", "filter/All/pagesize/10/currentpage/0", "popUp=true");
        return url;
    }
```

EDIT 2 : To make it more efficient, I got this actually. But this isn't working, I got a blank modale.

But this way look like really better, since it will search itself for admin module

```
public string GetEditUrlUser()
    {
        // dnndev.me/en-us/Admin/User-Accounts/ctl/Edit/mid/"+ModuleId+"/UserId/KEYFIELD/filter/All/pagesize/10/currentpage/0?popUp=true

        var moduleController = new ModuleController();
        var adminUserModule = moduleController.GetModuleByDefinition(PortalId, "User Accounts");
        var url = EditUrl(adminUserModule.TabID, "Edit", false, "mid="+adminUserModule.ModuleID, "userId=KEYFIELD");
        return url;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think, finally, I got it.

The ASCX code would be

```
<rad:GridTemplateColumn HeaderStyle-Width="0" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" AllowFiltering="False">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <a href="#" data-id="<%#((CustomerViewModel)Container.DataItem).UserID%>" class="e">
            <img src='<%=ResolveUrl("~/Icons/Sigma/Edit_16x16_Standard.png")%>' title='Edit user' />
        </a>
    </ItemTemplate>
</rad:GridTemplateColumn>
```

With somes Javascript Function for self-update without reload the page.

```
function refreshGrid() {
    // grdCustomers should be the ID of your grid
    $find("<%= grdCustomers.ClientID %>").get_masterTableView().rebind();
}

// edit user infos
$('.e').click(function () {
    var url = "<%= GetEditUrlUser() %>".replace(new RegExp("KEYFIELD", "g"), $(this).attr("data-id"));
    dnnModal.show(url,/*showReturn*/true, 550, 950, true, 'javascript:parent.window.refreshGrid()');
    return false;
});
```

And into the CS file, it should be like.

```
public string GetEditUrlUser()
{
    var moduleController = new ModuleController();
    var adminUserModule = moduleController.GetModuleByDefinition(PortalId, "User Accounts");
        var url = Globals.NavigateURL(adminUserModule.TabID, "Edit", "mid=" + adminUserModule.ModuleID, "userId=KEYFIELD", "popUp=true");
    return url;
}
```

And it work fine.

I hope it could help someone.